# How to limit speed of retrieved files with IndyFtpServer (v10)

Tags: delphi, ftp, indy, ftp-server

I'm developing a FTP Server with Delphi XE 6 and Indy10. The problem is that i need to limit the speed of download (must be configurable Ex. 1 KB/s, 1 MB/s, etc.) and i don't make it work. I know some props like BitsPerSec, etc. but this only affect the protocol data exchange, not the file exchange with RETR command. I see in IdFTPServer.pass, and the Stream is converted to string and send with a repeat/until loop (with IOHandler.Write()) but i need some form of control the upload/download process and be able to limit the speed for all incoming client connections. Some help to achieve this please?.

PD: Sorry for my poor english.

I try to implement a CommandHandler for the RETR command with this code:

```
procedure TForm1.IdFTPServer1CommandHandlers0Command(ASender: TIdCommand);
var
  LContext : TIdFTPServerContext;
  vStream: TFileStream;
  path: String;
  vX: Integer;
  LEncoding: IIdTextEncoding;
begin

  LEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_8Bit;
  LContext := ASender.Context as TIdFTPServerContext;
  path := 'D:\indy_in_depth.pdf';


  try
    vStream := TFileStream.Create(path, fmOpenRead);
    //LContext.DataChannel.FtpOperation := ftpRetr;
    //LContext.DataChannel.Data := VStream;
    LContext.DataChannel.OKReply.SetReply(226, RSFTPDataConnClosed);
    LContext.DataChannel.ErrorReply.SetReply(426, RSFTPDataConnClosedAbnormally);

    ASender.Reply.SetReply(150, RSFTPDataConnToOpen);
    ASender.SendReply;

    Memo1.Lines.Add('Sending a file with: ' + IntToStr(vStream.Size) + ' bytes');
    //Make control of speed here !
    for vX := 1 to vStream.Size do
      begin
        vStream.Position := vX;
        LContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(vStream, 1, False);
        if vX mod 10000 = 0 then
          Memo1.Lines.Add('Sended byte: ' + IntToStr(vX));
      end;

    //LContext.DataChannel.InitOperation(False);

    //LContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(vStream);

    //LContext.KillDataChannel;
    LContext.Connection.Socket.Close;

    VStream.Free;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      ASender.Reply.SetReply(550, E.Message);
    end;
  end;

end;
```

But the Filezilla FTP Client show stream data like part of other command.

[Filezilla Client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDdSD.jpg)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> The problem is that i need to limit the speed of download (must be configurable Ex. 1 KB/s, 1 MB/s, etc.) and i don't make it work. I know some props like `BitsPerSec`, etc. but this only affect the protocol data exchange, not the file exchange with `RETR` command.

`BitsPerSec` is a property of the `TIdInterceptThrottler` class (along with `RecvBitsPerSec` and `SendBitsPerSec` properties).  An instance of that class  can be assigned to any `TIdTCPConnection` object via its `Intercept` property.  This is not limited to just the command connection, it can be used for transfer connections, too.

You can access the `TIdTCPConnection` object of a file transfer in `TIdFTPServer` via the `TIdFTPServerContext.DataChannel.FDataChannel` member, such as in the `OnRetrieveFile` event:

```
type
  // the TIdDataChannel.FDataChannel member is 'protected',
  // so use an accessor class to reach it...
  TIdDataChannelAccess = class(TIdDataChannel)
  end;

procedure TForm1.IdFTPServer1RetrieveFile(ASender: TIdFTPServerContext;
  const AFileName: TIdFTPFileName; var VStream: TStream);
var
  Conn: TIdTCPConnection;
begin
  Conn := TIdDataChannelAccess(ASender.DataChannel).FDataChannel;
  if Conn.Intercept = nil then
    Conn.Intercept := TIdInterceptThrottler.Create(Conn);
  TIdInterceptThrottler(Conn.Intercept).BitsPerSec := ...;
  VStream := TFileStream.Create(AFileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
end;
```

An alternative is to create your own `T(File)Stream` derived class to override the virtual `Read()` and `Write()` methods to perform your own throttling as needed, and then assign an instance of that class to the `VStream` parameter of the `OnRetrieveFile` and `OnStoreFile` events.

> I see in `IdFTPServer.pas`, and the Stream is converted to string and send with a repeat/until loop (with IOHandler.Write())

No, a stream is not converted to a string.  You are misreading the code.  A stream's content is sent as-is as binary data in a single call to the `IOHandler.Write(TStream)` method.

> but i need some form of control the upload/download process and be able to limit the speed for all incoming client connections.

See above.

> I try to implement a CommandHandler for the RETR command

You should NOT be handling the `RETR` command *directly*.  `TIdFTPServer` already does that for you.  You are meant to use the `OnRetrieveFile` event instead to prepare downloads, and the `OnStoreFile` event for uploads.

Comment: You are the best bro. I do some mistakes reading the code, but just this is what i need. I be working 5 AM, so eyes and brain in bad conditions lol. I do some Throttle with you awesome class BufferedFileStream (with some calc and some sleeps). But now i see this and is the perfect way. Thanks a lot again !. With this rep i don't be able of make Up Votes Yet.